# Why enivironment variables inside .env.local will show undifined when i am using them in the directory called api located at root directory in next.js

Tags: mongodb, next.js, environment-variables

I am new to Web Development and next.js and i am trying to figure out that when i console.log my environment variables inside my page.jsx it shows the values correctly but when i try to console.log them in my router.js inside the api directory then they come as undefined also when i pass my mongodb  connection string which i saved in .env.local and pass it to mongoose.connect() in router.js it shows the following:

MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined".

router.js code:

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import { Dishes } from "./model.js";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server.js";
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';

dotenv.config();

const ConnectDB = async () => { 
    await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_STRING);
    const data = await Dishes.find();
    console.log("Db connected successfully");
    return NextResponse.json({result:data});
}

console.log(process.env.MONGO_STRING);
ConnectDB();
```

.env.local:

`MONGO_STRING=mongodb+srv://<my username>:<my pass>@cluster0.i4i4snw.mongodb.net/`

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "project-swadi",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "mongoose": "^8.0.0",
    "next": "13.5.6",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "react-icons": "^4.11.0",
    "swiper": "^11.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "autoprefixer": "^10",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.5.6",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "tailwindcss": "^3",
    "typescript": "^5"
  },
  "type": "module"
}
```

[next project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZmuY.png)

Comment: What are you using to work with `.env`, is it the npm `dotenv` package? If so, are you calling `require('dotenv').config();` in the api?

Comment: I added the dotenv in my project and imported and called the dotenv.config() just after importing and still it is showing undefined

Comment: I read https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/environment-variables and also followed a youtube tutorial and then simply made a .env.local file in my root directory to save the MongoDB connection string but inside api everyting is coming as undefined

Comment: Can you add your `package.json` to the question? I am curious how the application is starting, it may be a path issue somewhere.

Comment: Ok i will add package.json

Comment: I also tried to make another simple project without api directory for simplicity so i can get the .env file working but again i am getting undefined when i am trying to access them in src/app/products/route.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your `.env.local` file is in the root, the api folder might be looking in the wrong place. Generally you call the config at the earliest entry point and you only call it once for the entire project (for me, that would be my app.js in the root with package.json). Since you have an `app` and an `api` folder in the same project, I'm curious how it is being served.

Also, multiple .env files can be cumbersome so I would just use a main `.env` file and then you copy `.env.local` or `.env.prod` or whatever INTO that main `.env` when you want to use that connection. I believe `dotenv` is always looking for `.env` and nothing else.

Here is something I have used to test to make sure everything is referenced properly.

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const result = dotenv.config();
if (result.error) {
  throw result.error; // this will tell you if something is wrong or missing
}

// if the code above throws an error, this can be used instead to find a specific .env if it is in another location
require('dotenv').config({ path: '/path/to/your/.env.local' });
```

Comment: Ok i will try this

Answer (score 0):

You can installing dotenv and importing it in your router.js to explicitly load the environment variables before using them.

```
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv'; // Import the dotenv library.

dotenv.config(); // Load environment variables
```